# Exception error in "GetStartedWithData" in windowsazure tutorial with windows phone os

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am a beginner in windows azure and windows phone 8 development, recently i start following the tutorial on the windowsazure website but facing some problem.

But when i type something in the textbox and click the the save button 
this error will coming out.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

more details:

> - $exception  {System.NotSupportedException: The type 'GetStartedWithData.TodoItem' has one or members with a
>     DataMemberAttribute, but the type itself does not have a
>     DataContractAttribute. Use the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute
>     in place of the DataMemberAttribute and set the PropertyName to the
>     desired name.    at
>     Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) 
>     at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at
>     Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.d_*0.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>     at
>     GetStartedWithData.MainPage.d*_0.MoveNext()}  System.Exception
>     {System.NotSupportedException}

whats wrong with the code, i have followed every step in the tutorial.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure which tutorial you are referring to
...but I had the same exception a few minutes ago.

Make sure you decorate your entity class with the [DataContract] attribute...

In a mobile services example there were missing two attribute declarations:

```
[DataContract]
public class TodoItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; } (...)
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks a lot for the help, its very useful. i tried many times by adding try/catch clause even cut some code still having these exception error.

Comment: Do you have any experience on using azure mobile services in windows phone 8, i would like build one apps kind of social application to allow user to upload image and texts and can be view by other people. its actually my final year project haha

Comment: Hi Ken,

Long story short, this is a change we made to our API currently to align more closely with JSON.NET semantics. We will be updating the tutorial shortly, thanks for reporting the issue.

Dennis' suggestion is spot on.